# How to Record System Audio using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-recording, system-sounds, screen-recorder

It has come to my attention that some apps like camtasia have options to record system sounds / alert sounds (System Audio).

is there a way to capture system sounds without modificating windows system settings manually ? using ffmpeg ?